# Why doesn't a VueJS prop reactively update when it's an argument to a method?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I have this component with two text-fields with two expressions that should evaluate to the same thing.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ value.flange?value.circle.diameter:413 }}
    {{ get(value, 'circle.diameter') }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash/fp"

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
  },
  methods: {
    get (obj, path) {
      return _.get(obj, path)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

This is my attempt to guard my page from crashing on property look ups for the brief moment when `this.value` is undefined. I prefer to use lodash/fp's `_.get` function since it's a lot more readable and much less tedious for deeper nested objects.

However, when I load this page, I see brief momentary blip of 413 and nothing, which is expected. Since 413 is my placeholder value for the first expression and the second should be undefined. Then when `value` gets an update, the 413 quickly changes to `value.circle.diameter`, as it should, but the one wrapped in the `get` never updates.

Why is a method call blocking propagation and how should I in general guard against my deeply nested objects from crashing on property access when value is undefined?

Note: I don't want to block render of the page when the object is null with, for example, a `v-if="value"` on my `div`. This is because I want to be able to edit the value if it's `{}` and construct that structure as the user edits it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because properties are reactive and function calls are not. However, you can achieve this with computed properties:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ value.flange?value.circle.diameter:413 }}
    {{ diameter }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash/fp"

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
  },
  computed: {
    diameter: function () {
      return _.get(this.value, 'circle.diameter');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ug, this maybe correct but very expensive from a developer time and lines of code perspective. I have tens of inputs on a page that will all need to be turned into their own computed field. For every value.a.b I need a computed value. :(

Comment: For both Vue 2 and Vue 3 there is an article titled "Reactivity in Depth" on the vue.js website. I recommend you reading it, to understand why this is. You will see that it would quite a challenge from framework developer perspective to make that function call reactive.

Comment: Will do, thanks.